# Getting the values in the table centered

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Below is the way I have the formatting done:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textit{\textbf{Parameters}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Test (WOE)}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Test (WRE)}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{G}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{B}}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{W}}} 
\tabularnewline \hline
0.05\_0.025\_0.05\_0.2 & 24.86 & 37.67 &  &  & 
\tabularnewline \hline
0.05\_0.05\_0.05\_0.1 & 36.15 & 52.53 &  &  & 
\tabularnewline \hline
0.05\_0.075\_0.05\_0.2 & 24.23 & 35.30 &  &  & 
\tabularnewline \hline
0.1\_0.05\_0.2\_0.2 & 15.58 & 41.2 &  &  & 
\tabularnewline \hline
0.2\_0.05\_0.05\_0 & 18.78 & 52.98 &  &  & 
\tabularnewline \hline
0.2\_0.05\_0.1\_0.05 & 22.91 & 54.06 &  &  &
\tabularnewline \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{To add}
\label{table:to add}   
\end{table}
```

Seems like the centering isn't making the code work

the way the table looks as of now is as in the attached picture[image]

any advice would be much appriciated

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you add some additional information to your question? Do you explicitly want all columns to be equally wide? Do you need linebreaks inside of your table cells? If that's not the case, a simple `\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}` should already be sufficient.

Comment: Also, will your table contain more columns than you currently filled in? You define a total of 8 columns, but only seem to need 6 of them. Please clarify.

Comment: thanks, Leandriis, it is now solved. only from 2nd to last column i wanted them to be almost of the same length so that the table does not cross the limit of the column on the latext sheet. but now everything is solved. thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 3):

I assume the reason you wish to employ a `tabularx` environment is to ensure that the five data columns all have the exact same width.

I suggest you define a centered version of the `X` column type and remove the `\multicolumn` wrappers, which are preventing otherwise-sensible line breaks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of 'X'

\begin{document} 
\begin{table}[htbp]
%\centering %% redundant
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ |l| *{5}{C|} }
\hline 
\textit{\textbf{Parameters}} & 
\textit{\textbf{Test (WOE)}} &
\textit{\textbf{Test (WRE)}} &
\textit{\textbf{G}} &
\textit{\textbf{B}} &
\textit{\textbf{W}} \\ 
\hline
0.05\_0.025\_0.05\_0.2 & 24.86 & 37.67 &  &  & \\ 
\hline
0.05\_0.05\_0.05\_0.1  & 36.15 & 52.53 &  &  & \\ 
\hline
0.05\_0.075\_0.05\_0.2 & 24.23 & 35.30 &  &  & \\ 
\hline
0.1\_0.05\_0.2\_0.2    & 15.58 & 41.2\phantom{0} &  &  & \\ 
\hline
0.2\_0.05\_0.05\_0     & 18.78 & 52.98 &  &  & \\ 
\hline
0.2\_0.05\_0.1\_0.05   & 22.91 & 54.06 &  &  &\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{To add}
\label{table:to add}   
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like magic. thank you so very much

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that in all columns except first are decimal numbers with two integer and two decimal digits. In such a case they the following combination of `siunitx` and `siunitx` package can be handy. For column headers are defined two new commands: `\mcx`  and `\mr` as shortness for `\multirow{2}{*}{ ... }` (used in column heares where the cells span two line text):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\itshape\bfseries%
                                     \centering\arraybackslash}X|}{#1}}
\newcommand\mr[1]{\multirow{2}{*}{{#1}}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ |l| *{5}{S[table-format=2.2]|} }
    \hline
\mr{\textit{\textbf{Parameters}}} 
    &   \mcx{Test (WOE)}
        &   \mcx{Test (WRE)}
            &   \mcx{\mr{G}}
                &   \mcx{\mr{B}}
                    &   \mcx{\mr{W}}           \\
    \hline
0.05\_0.025\_0.05\_0.2 & 24.86 & 37.67 &  &  & \\
    \hline
0.05\_0.05\_0.05\_0.1  & 36.15 & 52.53 &  &  & \\
    \hline
0.05\_0.075\_0.05\_0.2 & 24.23 & 35.30 &  &  & \\
    \hline
0.1\_0.05\_0.2\_0.2    & 15.58 & 41.2  &  &  & \\
    \hline
0.2\_0.05\_0.05\_0     & 18.78 & 52.98 &  &  & \\
    \hline
0.2\_0.05\_0.1\_0.05   & 22.91 & 54.06 &  &  &\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{To add (table captions are usually at top of tables)}
\label{table:to add}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much @Zarko, for your response